# How implement as: parameter of attr_accessible of rails 3 to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, mass-assignment

I just upgraded from rails 3 to rails 4.2. So far everything is working just fine except a problem with `attr_accessible`. Previously in rails 3 I had some `attr_accessible` with `:as` parameter defined as below

```
attr_accessible :customer_id,:country_id, :city_id, :user_id, :as => [:default, :admin]
attr_accessible :archive, :as => :admin
```

Now, in rails 4, I can do something like this in the controller and update /create depending on the user is admin or not. But I wanted to know if there is a better way or standard way to do this? Or this is the right way?

```
private

def products_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:customer_id,:country_id, :city_id, :user_id)
end

def products_params_admin
  params.require(:product).permit(:customer_id,:country_id, :city_id, :user_id, :archive)
end
```

Comment: I would do it the way you propose, using strong parameters. See: https://blog.8thlight.com/will-warner/2014/04/05/strong-parameters-in-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `Gemfile` to have `attr_accessible` again:

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

IMO for stable projects it is reasonable manner, however strong parameters are more flexible, e.g. make possible passing attributes dependent on the object state.